# MySQL exhausting space in /root when explicitly asked to store DBs in another path

Tags: mysql

I am trying to store tables for different twitter sets. They are larger than usual , and hence, I changed the mysql conf file and directed it to store the tables on /home/username/mysql. Now, it does that. But when I am trying to make a table by loading it from a file, it initially stores temp files in root, which exhausts root space and I finally fail to write into the DB .

```
mysql> load data infile "/home/crazyabtliv/forSphinx.txt" into table Tweets fields terminated by '\t' lines terminated by '\n';
ERROR 3 (HY000): Error writing file '/var/tmp/mysql.jPIAWN/MLPINjsF' (Errcode: 28)
```

How do I tell mySQL to store the tables directly in the correct path and not take up memory on the root folders :( ?

Relevant portions of the conf file are below :

```
# Change following line if you want to store your database elsewhere
datadir = /home/crazyabtliv/mysql
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
log-bin=mysql-bin
server-id   = 1
# The safe_mysqld script
[safe_mysqld]
log-error   = /var/log/mysql/mysqld.log
socket      = /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock

!include_dir /etc/mysql

[mysqldump]
socket      = /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout

[mysqld_multi]
mysqld     = /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
mysqladmin = /usr/bin/mysqladmin
log        = /var/log/mysqld_multi.log
```

There is no tmpdir in the file. Am I looking at the wrong place ? Should I manually insert one ?

Comment: this is still not answered.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in your my.conf file for the tmpdir directive.